# DeepL API returns error for long text translation

Tags: javascript, ajax, deepl

I am using DeepL API to translate text and it is working fine. But if there is more than 4000 characters, it returns status as error without translating data.

```
https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate?&target_lang=en&auth_key=<auth_key>&text=dummy text;
```

So I used DeepL Api with multiple text query strings but still same issue.

```
https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate?&target_lang=en&auth_key=<auth_key>&text=dummy text&text=dummy text&text=dummy text;
```

Is there any way to translate the long text using DeepL API.

Comment: As [the docs](https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/accessing-the-api/limits/) say: *"The request size should not exceed 30kbytes"*. One solution would be to split your text up and send them as seperate requests.

Comment: Check out [Error handling](https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/accessing-the-api/error-handling/) for your specific error. My guess is a `414` error which tells you: *"The request URL is too long. You can avoid this error by using a POST request instead of a GET request."*

Comment: @Reyno,You are right. I spilt the text using new line character at particular length and create new request for remaining text. It worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Reyno says, I grouped mine into groups of 1000 texts and sent them in.